# How to use Redux in shared libraries in Angular

Tags: angular, redux, react-redux

I've got 3 Angular applications, which are using Redux (@angular-redux/store).

I need to develop library with components, which are shared between these 3. I would like to have rest calls and data state for them inside library.

How to use redux in this case? Is it possible to register state slice and reducers from library in application?

Or maybe it's not a good idea, and I should stick to make shared library only with presentational components?

Comment: It is really interesting, that noone answered. We do the same, and I am satisfied with it. To be honest however, we do not use redux directly, but we use akita state management. We even have services in the library, and it works great.